# Trouble connecting to SQL Server Express database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, permissions, sql-server-express

In my web application installed on IIS 7, I need to connect to a SQL Server Express database file (used for testing purposes only.) I use the following connection string in a web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbConnection" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;AttachDBFilename='C:\Users\UserName\CSharp\WebApp004_TestDB\App_Data\Database1.mdf';User Instance=true;Connection Timeout=15" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I also set up NTFS permissions for the `C:\Users\UserName\CSharp\WebApp004_TestDB\App_Data` folder as such:

- IIS_IUSRS = FullControl
- IUSR = FullControl
- NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS = FullControl
- IIS AppPool\[MyAppPoolName] = FullControl

That still didn't help. When I try to connect to that database via my C# code I get an exception:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\UserName\CSharp\WebApp004_TestDB\App_Data\Database1.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Note that the same code works on another machine with the actual SQL Server installed (with a different connection string where I used DB user name and password.)

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: at a guess the account sql server is running as can't see the file in your user folder. Given it's remote that's more than likely. Usual solution is to move the file onto the machine with the server into a folder the account has access to.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Thanks, good point. Indeed if I move the .mdf file into, say, "C:\Folder1" and make it publicly available, it works. Why doesn't it like my user folder? I thought setting those ACL permissions should do it.

Comment: You could run sql server under an account that could see your user folder if you were on the same machine. Might have to set one up though. Can't attach from a share though, so different machines is out, had similar issues with restore from disk. Gave up and just moved the files, and then used that path, too fragile, admins kept breaking it with active directory et al.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Yeah, I think I'm gonna give up as well and just go with a public folder. Strange though because I seemed to have set up all the necessary permissions that I could come across to that original folder in the users subtree...

Comment: In our case it was something to do with the Built in accounts sql server runs as. We took the quick, simple, flexible and manageable way out. Cowardly and unadventurous admittedly, there again, its still working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/)

Comment: Answers with just links are frowned upon, Answers with just links that are wrong, misleading or nothing to do with the problem, get really frowned at.

Comment: Just trying to be helpful, well they "Tesco" says every little helps :)